# neo4j - Find all nodes with relationships to nodes that match a list of property values of x length

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

To be more specific, I'd like to do the following (using node/JS if that is helpful):

Assume you have a list of 3 job criteria ('JavaScript', 'PHP', 'MySQL').

I have a graph setup where each `Person` node can be connected to many `Skill` nodes. I'd like to be able to run a query that will return all `Person` nodes that have connections to at least one and up to all of the skill nodes specified in the query and then sort by how many positive connections each User has. What is the most efficient way of making this query work if the job criteria is a variable?

Here is what I have so far. Again, this works but how do I make the `OR` statements a variable?

`MATCH (n:Persons)-[r:KNOWS]-(x:Skill)
WHERE x.name = 'PHP' OR x.name = 'JavaScript' OR x.name = 'MySql'
RETURN DISTINCT n
COUNT(n)
ORDER BY COUNT(n) DESC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `IN` operator to test if a value matches a value in a list.

```
MATCH (n:Persons)-[:KNOWS]-(x:Skill)
WHERE x.name IN ['PHP', 'JavaScript', 'MySql']
RETURN n, COUNT(x) AS nSkills
ORDER BY nSkills DESC;
```

Since the return clause uses the `COUNT()` function to [aggregate](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html) over `n`, it is redundant to use `DISTINCT n`, so the query omits `DISTINCT`.

Note: for efficiency, you should pass the list as a [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html). For example, if `needed_skills` was a parameter containing the list of skills, the query would look as follows:

```
MATCH (n:Persons)-[:KNOWS]-(x:Skill)
WHERE x.name IN {needed_skills}
RETURN n, COUNT(x) AS nSkills
ORDER BY nSkills DESC;
```

([Here is another example](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html#_multiple_node_ids)  of a list parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "making the `OR` statement a variable", but you can achieve the other part using `ORDER BY` and `COUNT`

```
MATCH (n:Persons)-[r:KNOWS]-(x:Skill)
WHERE x.name = 'PHP' OR x.name = 'JavaScript' OR x.name = 'MySql'
RETURN DISTINCT n, COUNT(r)
ORDER BY COUNT(r) DESC
```

You were using count to count(n) so it was not counting the number of skill they have. Once the count is done, you just have to order, like you already did.